Bend/kink a long square like a ribbon
I have an request for assistance. It's a bit embarrassing as it might be for you a simple question but I am not a native English speaker so I don't know on what specific terms to search either. The long square itself is in a 45 degree angle (see image 2). I want to know how can I kink it on a certain point and then bend it a certain degree?
I added another picture for the front view, I'm sorry for the confusion.


`


Do you know (1) edit mode, (2) loop cuts, (3) rotating on local axes ?

Yes but the problem is that the loop cut is in line with long square, the cut needs be horizontal on this 45 degree long square if you will, now it's also 45 degrees.

I hope I'm understanding your issue correctly, but I think using a mirror modifier with a mirror object can get you what you want. Docs

To shear the edge on the plane, select one vertex and press Shift V to slide it. Then rotate along an axis using the normal of the edge. (Select "Normal" in the Space dropdown instead of global/local/...)

Oh yes Leander I am getting very close to the desired result!!

You can slide verts and loops by just pressing G 2x (G, G). If you want to be more precise then use the Shear operator (Ctrl Alt Shift S). It's based on the view and the pivot point you're currently using (3D Cursor, Bounding Box, etc) and you can press X or Y to change direction while you're in the modal. Shear operator

Jakemoyo thanks for your suggestions! @Leander please formulate your solution in an answer so that I can accept it! And if you like it, a demonstration of how you would smooth the bend. Ty kindly all fellas in here.

Instead of the Loop Cut tool you could have used the Knife tool - it allows you to constrain the angle of the cut, so a horizontal cut would have been quite easy.

If you want to add a cut at an arbitrary angle, use the knife cut tool. K
To remove an edge, select the edge and press X > Dissolve Edges / Edge Loops
To modify and edge, you can slide the vertices along existing edges with GG or ShiftV.
To rotate around an edge, ...

select the edge and shift-box select (B) the other edges. Then choose active element as the pivot point and Normal as the Transform Orientation. The selection will rotate around the active edge (highlighted in a lighter yellow shade).
Rotate around the x-Normal of the edge. RX

To create a smoother transition at the bend, select the edge and bevel it. CtrlB
Adjust the count of divisions with the mouse wheel.

